# let-statement with SOME operator

Tags: isabelle

I find myself often wanting to write expressions of this form

```
let x = SOME x. x ∈ e1 
in e2
```

that is; let `x` be an arbitary member of `e1` in `e2`. It's rather verbose, and it seems a bit odd having to bind `x` twice. Is there a neater way to express this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simpler solution than copying the setup for `let` from HOL, namely, to extend the existing syntax translation for `let` by giving another production for `letbind`.

```
abbreviation Let_SOME :: "'a set => ('a => 'b) => 'b"
where "Let_SOME s f == let x = SOME x. x ∈ s in f x"

syntax
  "_bindSOME" :: "[pttrn, 'a] => letbind" ("(2_ ∈/ _)" 10)
translations
  "let x ∈ a in e" == "CONST Let_SOME a (%x. e)"
```

This has the advantage over your stand-alone solution that you can mix conventional `let` bindings with the new ones, as in

```
term "let x = 5; y ∈ {1,2}; z = 6 in x + y + z"
```

Answer (score 1):

I examined the way the `let x = e1 in e2` syntax is handled (http://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/HOL.html), and found I could mostly duplicate that mechanism to provide a new `let x ∈ e1 in e2` syntax. Here is my code (I just renamed `let` to `lett` throughout):

```
nonterminal lettbinds and lettbind
syntax
  "_bind"       :: "[pttrn, 'a] => lettbind"              ("(2_ ∈/ _)" 10)
  ""            :: "lettbind => lettbinds"                ("_")
  "_binds"      :: "[lettbind, lettbinds] => lettbinds"   ("_;/ _")
  "_Lett"       :: "[lettbinds, 'a] => 'a"                ("(let (_)/ in (_))" [0, 10] 10)

definition Lett :: "'a set ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ 'b"
  where "Lett s f ≡ let x = SOME x. x ∈ s in f x"

translations
  "_Lett (_binds b bs) e" == "_Lett b (_Lett bs e)"
  "let x ∈ a in e"        == "CONST Lett a (λx. e)"
```

As a quick test:

```
value "let x ∈ {2::int,3} in x+x"
```